# How to convert local gatsby plugin to Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I have a Gatsby project that was recently converted from Javascript to Typescript. All the code in src dir was converted but the code in plugins dir for my local plugins is still TS.

When I rename them to `<file_name>.ts`, they no longer run as part of the start script.

I have a simple file in my `plugins/<my_plugin>/gatsby-node.ts` which just has a console log. This does not run now:

```
// gatsby-node.ts
console.log("Running") // never runs
```

I have also added a `tsconfig` just for safe measure:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
}
```

Do I need to tell gatsby that the plugin in now TS some how or should it automatically pick it up?

Why does it not work now it's a typescript file?

Comment: What's your Gatsby version?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to tell gatsby that the plugin in now TS some how or should
> it automatically pick it up?

It should be automatically picked up as long as you have a Gatsby version `4.9.0` or greater, as the [docs points out](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/typescript/#local-plugins):

> ### Local Plugins
>
> > Support added in `gatsby@4.9.0`
>
> All the files mentioned above can also be written and used inside a
> [local plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-a-local-plugin/).

Comment: Ah I only have Gatsby V3. Do you know if there is a way to do it with V3?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-ts/ or https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-ts-config/ but since they're not official plugins I'm not sure about the drop-in support and the caveats using the. I'd recommend migrating from v3 to v4

Comment: Thanks, will check them out. We are looking at upgrading to v4 but hitting some snags so one of these packages might be a good temp solution. Cheers